# Rename Community bot's name to R2-D2

Tags: feature-request

We have a generic question on MSO: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235036/proposal-to-rename-community-user

This won't be suitable for all sites out there, but in site specific cases, it may work.

I suggest to rename Community to R2-D2.

Comment: I prefer the name "buffy" or "buffybot"

Comment: @Richard Yeah, I can see that on your DP.

Comment: Based on the one-winged angel in our banner, and to mix sci-fi and fantasy, what about [Icarus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icarus)?

Answer (score 5):

I see three potential objections:

1. R2-D2’s gender has never been absolutely confirmed (afaik), but a [note on his Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R2-D2#Notes) points to a source that suggests that it has “masculine programming”. By contrast, the Community user is known to [identify as female](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/226928).

   It would be unfair and inappropriate to force a gender change on Community.

   (Note, however, that this particular criticism would not affect Buffy.)
2. R2-D2 belongs to the *Star Wars* franchise, while this site has fans of many different fictional universes. Some users of the site may not even like *Star Wars*.

   It would be inappropriate to choose a new name for the Community user that does not represent most, if not all, of the site’s users.
3. You say that

   > This [change] won't be suitable for all sites out there, but in site specific cases, it may work.

   That may be true, but site-specific changes are also more-work-for-less-benefit for the SE Developers, compared to a change network-wide. And it would fragment us from the rest of the SE network.

   I can’t speak for them, but I think the SE Devs would be reluctant to make this change.

Comment: As for 2, I can start again about our primary chatroom name.